# Modify URL query value using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like modify value of single URL query (Itemid), but I need preserve all other query params (which can also change).

domain.com/index.php?id=1080&catid=51&**Itemid=93**

domain.com/index.php?id=672&catid=89&**Itemid=93**

domain.com/index.php?id=342&catid=23&**Itemid=93**

etc...

Change TO:

domain.com/index.php?id=1080&catid=51&**Itemid=144**

domain.com/index.php?id=672&catid=89&**Itemid=144**

domain.com/index.php?id=342&catid=23&**Itemid=144**

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=93 [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}?Itemid=144 [L,NC,R=301]
```

But not works...:(

Comment: `^$` demands that the request path is completely empty, but in your case it is `index.php`, so this rule does not match at all. And neither does the query string in your examples _start with_ `Itemid=93`, but by putting the `^` before it, you are demanding that to be the case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below I am assuming id and catid will be integer value.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\d]+)&catid=([\d]+)&Itemid=93$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{REQUEST_URI}?id=%1&cat=%2&Itemid=144 [L,NC,R=301]
```